# Android SDK Manager - What API to download?

Tags: android, sdk

In order to develop an app with minimum sdk API 10 do I need to have that API installed throught the sdk manager? Or API 22 (which is the latest) includes API 10?

Comment: @VJayakarEdidiah What are you saying? This is absolutely not true..

Comment: download api 22, you can set any minimum level for your app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be a short answer: No.

The API 22 package supports also all previous API. So you can simply download only api 22 (and obviously SDK-tools, build-tools and platform-tools). You don't need API 10. You can set minimum SDK in your gradle file or your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between those options, but your (test)device should also have API 10 installed. If you choose the second option (api 22) and have API 10 installed on the device, you run the risk of implementing code that will not compile. I would personally take the second option and test on a device with API 10.
You can also set the minimum SDK in your application manifest

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to download API 10.

android:minSdkVersion
"An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. "

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

API 22 is an upgrade (12th in a row).

If you do want to test your app on a device with API 10, I would just set the minimum SDK in your manifest to 10. Later on in the code, you'd see suggestions or possibly errors on the functions you use.